# Any books on isospectral manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was searching stuff related to M.Kac's famous question "[Can one hear the shape of the drum](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2313748) ?" I further found results due to [Gordon, Webb and Wolpert](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207215) in the 2D case using Sunada method. Are there any books on this topic explaining the above mentioned stuff and the recent advances? Thanks.

Comment: Check the homepage of Caroline Gordon, especially her expository articles.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think there is a book entirely dedicated to the isospectrality problem. However, take a look at [this survey](http://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~schueth/gps.pdf) and references given there.

Answer (score 1):

Check Chapter 3 of "Old and new aspects in spectral geometry" by Craioveanu, Puta and Rassias.